# Difference between MongoDB drivers

Tags: php, mongodb

What is the difference between MongoDB database driver and MongoDB driver for PHP.

I tried running ***pecl search mongo*** and got these two results.

```
Package Stable/(Latest) Local
mongo   1.6.13 (stable)       MongoDB database driver 
mongodb 1.1.5 (stable)        MongoDB driver for PHP
```

The only thing i need to do is update my PHP drivers for MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mongo.php) should be used instead of deprecated [Mongo](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.setup.php).
MongoDB supports new features from version 3.0.

Older database driver was stuck on version 2.6 and will now raise deprecation errors.